# How to replace html content with escape char in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We need to replace portion of the html content with jquery.

```
original_string = '<option value=\"\"><\/option>\n'
replacing_string = '<option value=""></option> <option value="11">2012/05/09</option> <option value="6">2012/07/03</option> '
$('#id').html().replace(original_string, replacing_string);
```

The problem is that there are bunch of escape chars in both original and replacing string and the `html().replace` can not be executed. How to replace a string with escape characters?
Thanks.

Basically we are dynamically adding an empty select option to the page. Based on user input, a select options need to be inserted into the content and be rendered to the screen. The html manipulation happens before rendering.

UPDATE: html content(sorry, it is massy)

```
<div id="invoice_against_lease" style="display: none;">
<a onclick="add_nest_fields(this, "invoice_items", "<div class=\"fields\">\n<div class=\"input select optional\"><label class=\"select optional\" for=\"invoice_invoice_items_attributes_new_invoice_items_lease_usage_record_id\">Record#：<\/label><select class=\"select optional\" id=\"invoice_invoice_items_attributes_new_invoice_items_lease_usage_record_id\" name=\"invoice[invoice_items_attributes][new_invoice_items][lease_usage_record_id]\"><option value=\"\"><\/option>\n<\/select><\/div>\n<input id=\"invoice_invoice_items_attributes_new_invoice_items__destroy\" name=\"invoice[invoice_items_attributes][new_invoice_items][_destroy]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"false\" /><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"remove_nest_fields(this); return false;\">Delete<\/a>\n<\/div>\n"); return false;" href="#">Add Record</a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you not have the option to build the elements via `var yourOption = $("option");` ?

Comment: It's not too clear what you are trying to do here.  Are you trying to manipulate string content or actually manipulate the HTML in the DOM?

Comment: Not sure if its related (could just be a copy paste mistake), but you are missing some semicolons at the end of the first two lines of code...

Comment: If you're wanting to replace one element with another element, select the one to replace and use `.replaceWith`, makes it much easier than trying to match exact html

Comment: We need to replace portion of the html content of the element. We want to replace an empty select option wiht a list of options.

Comment: You need to work with DOM, not html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$('#id')` is a reference to your `<select...` then you should be able to simply replace all of your options with `$('#id').html(replacing_string);`

EDIT:

If `$('#id')` is the id of the parent div, then the code only slightly changes :

`$('#id select').html(replacing_string);`

( unless, of course, you have more than one select in that div, then you'd have to provide more detail so that we can help you with the correct selector... )

Comment: NO, the #id is not the reference of select element. The whole content is within a div and is a dynamically added selection option and label. We want to insert a selection options and replace the empty one.

Comment: @user938363 Add a snap shot of the HTML at the time this is executed, that should be helpful